# how to set a default value(dollar or euros) in input text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to put a measuring unit (€, $) in a text field by default, which targets a number and you appear. How can I do it? Are  there any default value for this?

Thank you

[Example](http://imgur.com/r46pnHs)

Comment: You must show us what you have tried in order to get help from community here at SO.

Comment: @AlvaroGlez saqib meant put your code. A problem statement is very generic without context

Answer (score 0):

is this what you expect.try with this.

```
<input type="text" value="$"/>
```

if your want both use this

```
<input type="text" value="$,&euro;"/>
```

hope this will help to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
<form>
  <h2>Test Form</h2>
  Whats your hourly rate? 
   <select name="" id="">
     <option value="">€</option>
     <option value="">$</option>
     <option value="">£</option>
   </select>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="10000" step=".1" name="hourly_rate" id="hourly_rate" required="required">
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

here is a working **demo** - http://jsbin.com/dimobovixu/1/edit?html,css,output